# How to test DeferredResult timeoutResult

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test, spring-web

I'm implementing [long polling as per the Spring blog from some time ago](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application).

Here my converted method with same response signature as before, but instead of responding immediately, it now uses long polling:

```
private Map<String, DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>> requests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@RequestMapping(value = "/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> poll(@PathVariable("uuid") final String uuid) {
    // Create & store a new instance
    ResponseEntity<?> pendingOnTimeout = ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(TWENTYFIVE_SECONDS, pendingOnTimeout);
    requests.put(uuid, deferredResult);

    // Clean up poll requests when done
    deferredResult.onCompletion(() -> {
        requests.remove(deferredResult);
    });

    // Set result if already available
    Task task = taskHolder.retrieve(uuid);
    if (task == null)
        deferredResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.GONE).build());
    else
        // Done (or canceled): Redirect to retrieve file contents
        if (task.getFutureFile().isDone())
            deferredResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.created(RetrieveController.uri(uuid)).build());

    // Return result
    return deferredResult;
}
```

In particular I'd like to return the `pendingOnTimeout` response when the request takes too long (which I returned immediately before), to prevent proxies from cutting off the request.

Now I think I've gotten this working as is, but I'd like to write a unittest that confirms this. However all my attempts at using MockMvc (via webAppContextSetup) fail to provide me with a means of asserting that I get an `accepted` header. When I for instance try the following:

```
@Test
public void pollPending() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/poll/{uuid}", uuidPending)).andReturn();
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
            .andExpect(status().isAccepted());
}
```

I get the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async result for handler [public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult> nl.bioprodict.blast.api.PollController.poll(java.lang.String)] was not set during the specified timeToWait=25000
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch(MockMvcRequestBuilders.java:235)
>       at nl.bioprodict.blast.docs.PollControllerDocumentation.pollPending(PollControllerDocumentation.java:53)
>   ...

The Spring framework tests related to this that I could find all use mocking it seems: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncManagerTimeoutTests.java

How can I test the correct handling of the DeferredResult timeoutResult?

Comment: To be clear: It seems to work fine in integration tests, but I'd also want to test this in `spring-restdocs-mockmvc`.

Comment: I have just run into this exact same issue.  Did you ever find a solution that allows testing of the timeouts on DeferredResults?

Comment: @John nope, not yet, although I've stopped looking for now.. Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: @Tim I need to test the same case, were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @Tim, I just received the same error, and the cause was that the reference inside the `DeferredResult` was `null`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, after going through spring source code and setting the timeout (10000 millisecond) and getting async result solved it for me, as;

```
 mvcResult.getRequest().getAsyncContext().setTimeout(10000);
 mvcResult.getAsyncResult();
```

My whole test code was;

```
MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(
                                post("<SOME_RELATIVE_URL>")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(<JSON_DATA>))
                        ***.andExpect(request().asyncStarted())***
                            .andReturn();

***mvcResult.getRequest().getAsyncContext().setTimeout(10000);***
***mvcResult.getAsyncResult();***

this.mockMvc
    .perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted as I feel it might help someone out, but in my case it does not yet work either with `@SpringBootTest()` nor `@WebMvcTest(PollController.class)`. Both keep throwing up: `Deferred result was not set during the specified timeToWait=25000`.. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6):

I [ran across this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51549043/13317) using Spring 4.3, and managed to find a way to trigger the timeout callback from within the unit test. After getting the `MvcResult`, and before calling `asyncDispatch()`, you can insert code such as the following:

```
MockAsyncContext ctx = (MockAsyncContext) mvcResult.getRequest().getAsyncContext();
for (AsyncListener listener : ctx.getListeners()) {
    listener.onTimeout(null);
}
```

One of the async listeners for the request will invoke the `DeferredResult`'s timeout callback.

So your unit test would look like this:

```
@Test
public void pollPending() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/poll/{uuid}", uuidPending)).andReturn();
    MockAsyncContext ctx = (MockAsyncContext) result.getRequest().getAsyncContext();
    for (AsyncListener listener : ctx.getListeners()) {
        listener.onTimeout(null);
    }
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
            .andExpect(status().isAccepted());
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, is the only that work for me