# Spring DeferredResult onCompletion not called from test cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a comet(long polling) `Controller` call, which takes in some ids and `puts` then into a blocking queue if no calculation for that id is running, for a `Consumer` to `take` from the `queue` and perform computations on these ids. I am using `Springs` `DeferredResult` for asynch support.

I maintain a `Map` of `DeferredResult` and the corresponding ids that were received in a request. When the calculations for a id are complete in the consumer thread I check for this id in the `Map` and set the associated `DeferredResults` `setResult` which send the response back to the client.

In the `Controller` method I have an `onCompletion` callback of `DeferredResult` which removes this `DeferredResult` object from the `Map`.

The client then removes this id from its request and sends the remaining ids. As as example say the client send initially ids "1,2,3" they all got inserted into `BlockingQueue` and say the calculation for id "2" was finished earlier, then its `DeferredResults` `setResult` will be set, which will return the response to the client. And through the callback this `DeferredResult` will be removed from the `Map`. And the client in the next request will send ids "1, 3".

Now all works fine, but when I started writing test cases for this the `onCompletion` callback is never called. I even tried it in the springs official examples it does not seem to be called even there. Is there a way to call it, or something is incorrect in my implementation.

This is my `Controller` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "views/getLongPollingGraphData", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse> getLongGraphData(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "ids") String ids) 
{
    //create a default response in case, when no result has been calculated till timeout
    WebServiceResponse awrDefault = new WebServiceResponse();

    //set time out this DeferredResult, after 5 seconds 
    final DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<WebServiceResponse>(5000L, awrDefault);

    //logic to set in blocking queue
    //mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews.put(deferredResult, listOfViews.keySet());

    deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            mMapOfDeferredResultAndViews.remove(deferredResult);
        }
    });

    return deferredResult;
}
```

Below is a part of the test case:

```
@Before
public void setup() 
{
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void testLongPollGraphData()
{
    try
    {         
        String ids = "22,23,25";
        List<Integer> idList = convertStringToList(ids);

        while(idList.size() > 0)
        {
            MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/views/getLongPollingGraphData")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .param("ids", ids)          
                .andReturn();

            this.mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult));
            WebServiceResponse result = (WebServiceResponse)mvcResult.getAsyncResult();

            if(result != null)
            {
                EJSChartsData chartsData = (EJSChartsData)result.getResponse();
                if(chartsData != null && chartsData.getViewId() != -1)
                {
                    int viewId = chartsData.getViewId();
                    idList.remove((Integer)viewId);
                    ids = idList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        fail(e.toString());
    }
}
```

The `Controller` method is called and I receive the response as expected, but as the `onCompletion` callback is never called my logic of calling the method again by removing the id takes a hit as the `Map` holds on the past `DeferredResult`.

**Update**

The test class annotations are:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test-context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I have another observation, the call to `getLongPollingGraphData` is not completed, i.e. it does not wait for the specified timeout of 5 seconds and returns immediately causing the `result` to be `null`. I read about it and the recommendation is to add `.andExpect(request().asyncResult("Expected output"))` to `mockMvc` object.

But this is the whole point of my test case, I want the result to be calculated and returned so that I can resend a request modifying my ids variable based on the response received.

Comment: Show your Test Class Annotations at top

Comment: @shazin updated in the question, with some additional observations.

Comment: Do you use tomcat for your web application?

Comment: @eg04lt3r Yes, I do.

Comment: @eg04lt3r But what does it has to do with the test case?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly when I say you specifically want to test the behaviour when a timeout occurs?

Comment: I tried to write test for my custom controller which return deferredresult with some timeout and default value. I set nothing as result and I was expecting that I receive default value after timeout released. But I had no luck just error that async result still empty after timeout. Also I have not seen anywhere in spring tests this test case.

Comment: @eg04lt3r Yes this is what I have observed. However the async result could be waited for using `asyncDispatch()` and expecting the result while `mockMvc.perform()` atleast this is what the test cases said in Springs. Surprisingly there is no mention of timeout and `onComplete`.

Comment: @Leon No, I want my `onComplete` to be called when the response is returned from the controller.

Comment: @rd22 What I mean is you want to check that onComplete is called when you receive a timeout. If that is the case you are not alone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343231/how-to-test-deferredresult-timeoutresult

Comment: @Leon Yes, I could find this question, I even posted a comment asking if he was able to achieve it. Nevertheless calling `onComplete` on timeout is one requirement, other is to call it when a normal response is send.

Comment: @rd22, the main problem is in DefaultMvcResult::getAsyncResult. It uses defined timeout and checking if result set during  timeout, if not raise exception. It is not using timeoutResult, and I think it's not proper implementation of this method. Because I tested my controller with curl, and  I received default result and onComplete was called.

Comment: @rd22, Also obvious that timeoutResult should be set as result only after timeout released. Current code (DefaultMvcResult) does not support this  behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spring are you using?
I've opened [SPR-13615](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13615) for a similar case and it got fixed in 4.2.3 (affects 4.2.2).

If you look at the comments, you can workaround it without updating by using

```
    mvcResult.getRequest().getAsyncContext().complete();
```