# spring-mvc: how to test Rx responses with mockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, rx-java

my controller is:

```
import rx.Single;
...

@GetMapping
Single<List<MyType>> fetchFromDB() {
        return Single
                .fromCallable(() -> dao.fetch())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

and it works perfectly. but i can't tests it. i tried:

```
 MvcResult asyncResult = mvc.perform(get("/")).andReturn()

 String result = mvc
                    .perform(asyncDispatch(asyncResult))
                    .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString()
```

but it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async result for handler [rx.Single<java.util.List<MyType>> MyController.fetchFromDB()] was not set during the specified timeToWait=-1

    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch(MockMvcRequestBuilders.java:246)
    at MyControllerSpec.should fetch from db...
```

so: how to test `rx.Single` with spring mvc?

Comment: Please check answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033122/1290868)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer. when you create your mockMvc object, add a handler for `Single`:

```
return MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .setCustomReturnValueHandlers(new SingleReturnValueHandler())
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)` instead, you can add the handler in your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
        returnValueHandlers.add(new SingleReturnValueHandler());
    }
}
```