# Spring MVC unit test for DeferredResult doesn't call timeout callback

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm using Spring 4.3.18 and Spring Boot 1.5.14 on Java 7.

I'm implementing a RestController endpoint which returns a `DeferredResult` with a timeout callback. I'm trying to write a unit test for the timeout callback, but I can't get a `MockMvc` unit test to call the timeout callback.

For the sake of testing, I wrote this endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public DeferredResult<String>
testit() {
    logger.info("testit called");
    final DeferredResult<String> rv = new DeferredResult<>(1000L);
    rv.onTimeout(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("run called");
            rv.setResult("timed out");
        }
    });
    return rv;
}
```

and this unit test:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void testTest() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/tasks/test"))
        .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
        .andReturn();
    result.getAsyncResult(1500);
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        ;
}
```

(The call to `result.getAsyncResult(1500)` is based on https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16869)

When I run this, the `testit()` endpoint is called, and after a 1500 ms delay, I get an exception complaining that `setResult()` was never called. The timeout handler isn't invoked:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async result for handler [public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String> my.package.TasksController.testit()] was not set during the specified timeToWait=1500
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:135)
    at my.package.TasksControllerTest.testTest(TasksControllerTest.java:200)
```

```
2517 [main] INFO my.package.TasksController - testit called

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /rest/tasks/test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

Handler:
             Type = my.package.TasksController
           Method = public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<java.lang.String> my.package.TasksController.testit()

Async:
    Async started = true
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
4037 [Thread-2] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6ea91f6: startup date [Thu Jul 26 19:44:31 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

What do I need to do to make the test framework invoke the timeout handler on the DeferredResult?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it's possible to create a synthetic timeout in the unit test like this:

```
@Test
public void testTest() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/tasks/test"))
        .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
        .andReturn();
    // Trigger a timeout on the request
    MockAsyncContext ctx = (MockAsyncContext) result.getRequest().getAsyncContext();
    for (AsyncListener listener : ctx.getListeners()) {
        listener.onTimeout(null);
    }
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        ;
}
```

Accessing the request's async listeners and calling `onTimeout()` will result in calling the `DeferredRequest`'s timeout callback.

The call to `result.getAsyncResult(1500)` from my question is redundant for this test, because `asyncDispatch()` will call `getAsyncResult()` anyway.

Comment: but why it does not called by spring itself?